# Chrome 63+ throws [DOM] error with input type password and non-unique ids

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

From Chrome 63, the following error is thrown:

> [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #a: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq)

https://jsfiddle.net/arnabgh/jz186qxe/

```
<input type="password">
<input id="a">
<input id="a">
```

Is there any special validation happening when input type password is used, starting from Chrome 63?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is; that's why you're seeing that message. But I suspect that's not what you're really asking.

If your question is *why* Chrome has started displaying this message, my guess is that since passworded forms tend to transmit sensitive information (namely, a password), any errors in passworded forms should be brought to the developer's attention immediately. Greater care should be taken when designing and implementing passworded forms.

The document the error message links to (which I cannot assume that you've read since you've made no acknowledgement of it in your question) has a subsection on writing standards-compliant HTML, in which the unique ID rule is re-stated:

> ### Follow HTML guidelines
>
> Web browsers are designed with the HTML specification in mind, and going against it can lead to unexpected issues with your web page. This means:
>
> Element `id` attributes should be unique: no two elements should have the same `id`.

(Why that rule is the only one that's there is anyone's guess; it certainly looks like they intend to add more in the future, but it's still strange that they'd put out a document with just this one rule and call it good.)

There does not appear to be a way to disable this message, but since it doesn't prevent the page from working beyond how the duplicate IDs would have (and they don't either), if you're unable to correct the non-unique IDs yourself it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: Sometimes it is too difficult to watch about unique ids. For examole comment widget was with id, binded to css and js. Soon someone wants two comment-widgets on one page - and programmers don't want rewrite much code, just to follow specification. Because last ten year browsers ignored multiple id on HTML-pages, 80% big sites in console give this error on some pages, it cuts the eye: everyone expects from google convenient tools, not lobbying standards.

Comment: @Alexander Goncharov: I sympathize with that predicament, but I don't represent Google, the Chrome team, or any standards body; if you want to express disagreement with this decision, take it up with them, don't [downvote my answer just because it's not what you wanted to hear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_the_messenger). Besides, I did say that you can ignore this warning because it doesn't break your page any more than duplicate IDs already would have, so if you don't see a need to fix them, why are you letting the warning bother you so much?

Comment: The issues here is that this warnings are polluting other real errors making it less readable it would be great to have an option to hide them. I agree with Alexander it's a bit spamming about standards

Comment: @Mark Amery: With the link now added to the question, the issue of misrepresenting the error message is resolved but it's also made even more obvious the lack of any acknowledgement of that link (to such an extent that the question simply couldn't exist unless to say the asker considered and needed clarification on its contents). So, I feel that my statement to that effect still stands. And, to be honest, I've no idea what I want to do with my downvote on the question either.

Comment: @benraay: I suggest filing a feature request allowing warnings, or at least this specific group of warnings, to be hidden. These warnings are useful during development *to a point*, but they definitely do get in the way when you're either dealing with a legacy or complex codebase, or a framework that actively flouts the standards altogether - or you (the developer) are the one choosing to flout them yourself.

Comment: @BoltClock Not sure when it was implemented but it looks like you can filter.  At the top of the console window is a dropdown for "Default levels" that you can select individually.  Deselecting "Warnings" appears to remove this message.  You can also filter with a Google-like search.  For example, "-DOM" in the filter hides these messages as well.

Comment: @Michael Bray: Thanks, that might've been there for a while. The ability to use - to exclude messages seems like one of those "you'd have to remember this is a Google product to know this feature" things and even then it would never have crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `id='a'` use  `class='a'` with unique name, and then use with .a in or you can use unique id different then other field id like `id='a'` and other field like `id='b'`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `[id]` try using `[attr.id]`

This worked for me hope it helps.