# Found 2 elements with non-unique id #__VIEWSTATE

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I am working on a legacy ASP.NET application that renders two forms on a single web page. Each form implements its own `__VIEWSTATE` field.

Since Chrome v63 duplicate field names throw an error in the console:

> Found 2 elements with non-unique id #__VIEWSTATE

I don't have the luxury of rewriting the application to remove the duplicated forms. Is there another way to rename the `__VIEWSTATE` fields, or some other work around?

Comment: The `__VIEWSTATE` input field is added by the framework itself. Even with multiple user controls on a page, there will only be a single ViewState field. So unless you add them yourself, there should not be more than 1.

Comment: @VDWWD - there are multiple form elements on the page, and I believe that each one creates VIEWSTATE. This is an ASP.NET 2 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Page` class there are two methods that saves and loads view state. By overriding these two methods and set them to use another hidden filed you can rename `__VIEWSTATE` for that page.

Here's how you can do it:

```
public partial class SamplePage : Page
{
    const string ViewStateHiddenFiledName = "_VIEWSTATE_Page1";

    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        los.Serialize(writer, viewState);

        string serilizedViewState = writer.ToString();

        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(ViewStateHiddenFiledName, serilizedViewState);
    }

    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        string serilizedViewState = Request.Form[ViewStateHiddenFiledName];
        if (serilizedViewState != "")
        {
            LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter();
            return los.Deserialize(serilizedViewState);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no server-side interactivity between controls from these forms, as another way to get rid of the second form, it is possible to move it to a separate ASPx page/form and load it via an iframe:

Pseudo-code:

Old 2 Forms Page (not sure, how it is ever possible):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Root Page - Form 1
</form>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    Root Page - Form 2
</form>
```

New 2 Forms Page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Root Page - Form 1
</form>
<%--
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    Root Page - Form 2
</form>
--%>
<iframe src="Nested.aspx"></iframe>
```

Nested.aspx:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    Root Page - Form 2
</form>
```

As for the aforementioned Google Chrome error, it is a [newer feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806187/) of a newer browser builds.